# Getting Ajax error after successful mongoose save

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, mongodb

hope somebody can help me.
After successful save() with Mongoose the res to Ajax give an Error.
It gets to the console.log but it return an error in my Ajax.

Thanks in advance

```
app.post('/api/addItem', function (req, res) {
    var newProdukt = new Produkt(req.body);
    newProdukt.save().then(function(data){
        console.log('added');
        res.json(data);
    },function(e){
       res.json(e);
    });
});

  $.ajax({
        url:'api/addItem',
        data:createNewItem(),
        type:'POST',
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        error:function(e){
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Your res is not available in the next function scope. Save the res in some global variable then use it in save promise

Comment: please write the error you get

Comment: I just resolved the problem.I had method=post in my <form> in my html.
After i removed it everything works.
But thank you very much for the quick responses